# A different approach to the question: Determine max $|z^3 − z + 2|$. $z∈\Bbb C, |z|=1 $

Tags: complex-numbers

Determine max $|z^3 − z + 2|$.
$z∈\Bbb C, |z|=1 $

Now, quite clearly, substituting $z = x + iy$ makes the question easy.
The [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252505/how-find-max-z-z-1-f-left-z-right-for-f-left-z-right-z?noredirect=1&lq=1) is not very difficult after that.
However, is there some other (shorter or longer) method to solve it and is a **geometrical perspective** possible?

Finally, have you seen something **similar being used practically**?
These questions to maximize an expression are quite common.

Comment: See the second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252505/how-find-max-z-z-1-f-left-z-right-for-f-left-z-right-z) for a trig solution.

Comment: @dxiv Useful...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How find $\max _{z: \ |z|=1} \ f \left( z \right)$ for $f \left( z \right) = |z^3 - z +2|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252505/how-find-max-z-z-1-f-left-z-right-for-f-left-z-right-z)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for that.  Do you have something to mention regarding the other parts of the question?

Comment: You can interpret complex numbers geometrically ($z$ is on the complex unit circle, $1/z$ is reflection in the x axis, magnitude is distance to origin, etc.) However, it’s rare for algebra to have a nice geometric interpretation and more common for complex numbers/algebra being used to bash geometric problems. Maximization problems are common, but solving them is usually easily done with calculus or numerical approximation.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for that.